# Probability function on k items with different prices

Tags: probability, marketing

Is there a mathematical way to study problems like the following:

> I have 3 items $A$, $B$, $C$ and their 3 respective prices $x$, $y$, $z$. How to measure the propensity of a potential customer in selecting a particular item among the three mentioned?

Also some links would be very useful.

Comment: Economists often use so-called discrete choice models (particularly logit and probit) in this context.  See http://eml.berkeley.edu/books/train1201.pdf or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_latent-variable_model for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. There are plenty of them actually. [Luce's choice axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luce%27s_choice_axiom) is a good start. Assuming all the prices are positive, you can make the following assumption :

$$P(A)=\frac{x^\alpha}{x^\alpha+y^\alpha+z^\alpha}$$

Where $P(A)$ represents the probability to chose article $A$. If $\alpha$ is positive, the probability to chose an article will be increasing with its price. Maybe you want to use $\alpha<0$. The more expensive an article is, the less likely it is to be chosen.

Note that $\alpha=0$ represents insensitivity with respect to the price.

A more general answer would be to chose $f$, a weighting function (that is, in general decreasing, but you could relax this hypothesis) that associates a weight to a price and generate:
$$P(A)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(y)+f(z)}$$

But $f$ becomes complicated to estimate. On the other hand, if you have a limited number of observations (you know that $n$ customers faced $k$ products and chose a specific one), you can estimate $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ easily with maximum likelihood (or any other method).